# Why doesnt 'ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged' even occur when i select item from the list?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wrote code in C# for ASP.Net website , but when i select one item from the list above even doesn't occur and the execution goes back to Site.Master. I have to put a button to fetch the item from the list, how can i make that even occur when i select the item from list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're not using `UpdatePanel` controls, it should be as simple as setting the [`AutoPostBack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.autopostback.aspx) property of your list to true. If this is false then the event won't occur until the form is submitted otherwise.

```
<asp:ListBox AutoPostBack="true" ...>
```